# Nest.js: Circular dependencies in dynamic modules

Tags: module, nestjs, circular-dependency

What is the correct way to import dynamic modules when there's a circular dependency between them? I simply changed `forwardRef(() => MyModule)` to `forwardRef(() => MyModule.forRoot())`, and I'm getting `Nest can't resolve dependencies` error.

Comment: Could you share your module definitions please. Also, if you can avoid circular it’s better some times you can’t but otherwise its an architectural issue

Answer (score 25):

The best way to deal with nest module dependency is to import dependencies always through modules and never through services. If you run into a circular dependency, nest will show you an error and you can easily fix it with forwardRef().

let say your application has 3 tightly coupled modules.

- @moduleA()
- @moduleB()
- @moduleC()

And two supporting modules

- @moduleX()
- @moduleY()
- @moduleZ()

Also, all modules are exporting services with the same name.

Consider a situation where

> @moduleA() imports [serviceB, serviceX]

And

> @moduleB() imports [serviceA, serviceY, serviceZ]

Now in `@moduleC()` if you want to use serivceA() then you will have to

> @moduleC() imports [serviceA, serviceB, serviceX, serviceY, serviceZ]

In most cases, nest throws the correct error saying which dependency is missing where. But some times, nest only says dependency at [`index`] is missing, nest doesn't says where it is missing. This will lead to great level of confusion.

A neat approach is to always import modules

> @moduleA() imports [moduleB, moduleX]
>
> @moduleB() imports [moduleA, moduleY, moduleZ]
>
> @moduleC() imports [moduleA]

---

If nest is complaining again about dependency issue then import modules using `forwardRef`

```
@module({
     imports: [
       forwardRef(() => ModuleA)
       ModuleB
       ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: []
})
```

---

Sometimes even after doing all these, you may again run into dependency not available error. Then you can use `ModuleRef`. Let's take the same example where you want to use ServiceA() in ModuleC()

You will then be adding serviceA() to providers[] in ModuleC() and in the serviceC() class you need to add the following.

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common'; \\need OnModuleInit 
import { ServiceA} from '../FolderA/serviceA.service';

export class ServiceC implements OnModuleInit {
   
   private serviceA: ServiceA;
   constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

   onModuleInit() {
        this.serviceA= this.moduleRef.get(ServiceA);
    }
   
   foo(){
     console.log(this.serviceA.someFunction())
   }
}
```

Please check more at [Official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency).

Comment: If anyone is certain they don't have circular dependencies, but still get this error message, pay close attention to your `imports` property in `*.module.ts`. I found that having two commas, like `,,` causes this error.

Comment: Your solution is awesome , sir. But in my case, I need to pass { strict: false } option as a second argument to get().
Hope this can help someone ^^

Comment: Similarly as Alec pointed out, I didn't have circular dependencies among the the services, etc, but I had a constant defined in the module.ts that I imported in one of the services. Took me quite some time to understand the cause.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was a silly one.

I had an extra comma in the Providers array of the module which I assume caused Nest to try and resolve and nonexisting provider. Removing the comma fixed it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and I know that I can solve this issue using `forwardRef()` but I didn't know where exactly I can put `forwardRef()`.

Actually, the nestjs error shows where I have to put `forwardRef()`. Let's have a look at the following error:

```
Error: Nest cannot create the AuthModule instance.
The module at index [3] of the AuthModule "imports" array is undefined.
```

My `auth.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    OccasionModule,
    forwardRef(() => OrderModule),
    BalanceModule,
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,
    ReferralModule,
    RoleModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtSecret,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{
      name: OTP.name,
      schema: OTPSchema
    }]),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    LocalStrategy,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [
    AuthService
  ],
})
```

In my case `module at index [3] of the AuthModule "imports" array` is `UserModule` so I have to use `forwardRef()` there and my `auth.module.ts` will become:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    OccasionModule,
    forwardRef(() => OrderModule),
    BalanceModule,
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
    PassportModule,
    ReferralModule,
    RoleModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtSecret,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{
      name: OTP.name,
      schema: OTPSchema
    }]),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    LocalStrategy,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [
    AuthService
  ],
})

export class AuthModule { }
```

Also don't forget to change

```
private userService:
            UserService,
```

to

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() =>
            UserService
        ))
        private userService:
            UserService,
```

in the `auth.service.ts`.

After doing this you might get another dependency issue but with a different [index] of another Module. If you keep repeating the above process to add `forwardRef()` then you will eventually solve the circular dependency issue.

But it's not good to have too many circular dependencies. It's better to design modules of your project in such a way that you get minimum possible or no circular dependency.